# Broken Derailleur

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, compatibility

I have the GT Palomar 2001 edition mountain bike and the derailleur broke last year. I am now looking to fix it but I do not know which one to get as i do not want to do anything to the chain. Please can I have some help! thanks

Comment: Buy a new derailer of the same style.  In almost all cases you can disassemble the derailer to a degree to allow it to be fastened around an existing chain, if you're too timid to "break" the chain.  Just be sure you reassemble it correctly, with the chain through the proper passages.

Comment: Without knowing what components you have on your bike we can't say anything more than replace the derailleur with the same model, but that of course may be difficult for a 19 year old bike. Do you know what model derailleur or shifters you have? How many sprockets in the rear cluster? How many chainrings on the crank? If you can include a picture of the derailleur in your question someone can identify it.

Comment: Do you still have the old broken one ?

Answer (score 4):

Looking up the year, make and model of your bike on [Bicycle Blue Book](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/value-guide/product/35496/) doesn't yield the make of the rear derailleur, but one can see it's a seven speed in the rear.  Thus, you would want an RD compatible for that number of cogs.  Since it appears the stock shifter on your bike is from SRAM, you'll want to get a SRAM rear derailleur.  Whether the derailleur is marketed as 7,8, or 9 speeds doesn't matter as all these "speeds" of RD will work correctly with your shifter.  If it happens that you have Shimano shifters, you'll need to stick with a Shimano rear derailleur. The same thing goes for the marketed speeds of a Shimano RD: 7, 8, or 9 "speed" all work the same for a 7, 8 or 9 speed Shimano shifter. 
(Front derailleurs are different.  You can mix brands of shifter and derailleur with normal function.  Bikes with a "mountain mix" of components will often have SRAM shifters and Shimano front derailleur's).

Here's some examples of derailleur's that will work for you (not a product endorsement, just examples):
If you have SRAM shifters: [SRAM X3 RD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01F1H7KJ0)

If you have Shimano shifters: [Shimano Tourney RD](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/tourney/RD-TY300-SGS.html).

Almost all rear derailleurs can have their cages opened up by removing the bolt that serves as the axle for the lower tension pulley wheel. Separate the two halves of the cage by rotating them apart around the still attached upper jockey wheel axle.  Now you can remove the derailleur fixing bolt of the broken derailleur and take the whole unit off the chain while the chain remains on the front chainwheel and rear cassette.  I find it best when attaching the new derailleur (also with it's cage separated as above), to correctly route the chain, close the cage, replacing the lower tension wheel, then secure the derailleur with it's fixing bolt. Route the shift cable last and secure with the pinch bolt.